# Mark a Business Object as dirty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, business-objects

I have checkbox list bind to a Business Object Collection of List<>. When an item is checked in my checkbox list, I want to mark the selected business object as dirty.

1. How can I fetch the current business object on row click and change its property?
2. Also, how would this shape in a multi-user environment?

Comment: This is in reference with the following thread as I made some progress.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581791/changed-rows-from-list-of-objects

Comment: This isn't an answer and may not actually be helpful so take it with caution, but have you considered the unit of work design pattern. When users are editing them you can send there changes in one go to the server and then notify any other connected clients of the changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really a question about concurrency: How do you have multiple users modifying the same business objects and be confident each of their edits will be saved successfully.

If you are storing your objects in the cache, you can create a partial object to include a "IsDirty" boolean property.  As an item is checked, you set the IsDirty property of the relevant object to true.

There are many ways to handle concurrency and one way you can try is to check the IsDirty property when an item is checked.  If the property is false, you set the property to true.  If the property is already true, you send back an error to the user.  Once the object is saved, you reset the IsDirty property back to false.

Things can get more and more complicated as you try to get more sophisticated with the rules you create for saving your objects.

Comment: thank you Alison. Would not making a base class with IS Dirty and ISNEW solve the problem. That way each class would inherit the base and there will be no need to set ISDIRTY back to false on save ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list in view-state/session-state/cache or re-fetch from database on post-back then you can mark business object based on index. Personally, I will choose to get business object list via a wrapper method that will look it into cache and if not there then fetch it from database - that would allow to have small cache expiration time.

In multi-user scenario, it will depend upon how you are managing the concurrency. See this [article](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030604.htm) for quick-start on concurrency in ASP.NET.